# Declaring a variable for an object I made in C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, declaration

I am a Java guy and I'm trying to do an assignment with C++ for a class. I am having trouble declaring a variable of a type I created as a property of another class. This is my approach

```
  private:
    HeatingUnit heatingUnit;
    int tempToMaintain;

  public:
    BangBangControl(int tempToMaintain, bool isOn, int initialTemp){
      heatingUnit= new HeatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp);
      this -> tempToMaintain = tempToMaintain;
    }
```

I get this error

```
BangBangControl.cpp: In constructor ‘BangBangControl::BangBangControl(int, bool, int)’:
BangBangControl.cpp:15: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((BangBangControl*)this)->BangBangControl::heatingUnit = (((HeatingUnit*)operator new(8u)), (<anonymous>->HeatingUnit::HeatingUnit(((int)isOn), initialTemp), <anonymous>))’
HeatingUnit.h:6: note: candidates are: HeatingUnit& HeatingUnit::operator=(const HeatingUnit&)
BangBangControl.cpp: In member function ‘int BangBangControl::main()’:
BangBangControl.cpp:37: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Temp to maintain is: ")))->std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](bBC. BangBangControl::getTemp()))), ((const char*)" Current temp is: ")) << bBC. BangBangControl::update()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:112: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:121: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:131: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:177: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:92: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:184: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:106: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:195: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:208: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:217: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:229: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ostream.tcc:120: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Comment: Maybe you should remove your `java` tag from this question as it has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: He should also remove his `[java]` mindset.

Comment: It's worth noting that in C++, constructors don't work the same as Java. In Java, the syntax is _always_ `Thing a = new Thing();`, but in C++, that syntax is only when you want to create an object on the heap. If you want to construct an actual object, you should create it as `Thing a;` or, with parameters, `Thing a(1, 2, "red", "blue");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HeatingUnit heatingUnit;
```

should be:

```
HeatingUnit *heatingUnit;
            ^^
```

I believe your intention is to create a pointer of the type `HeatingUnit` since you use `new` inside the constructor. `new` is used to allocate memory on free store to pointer variables.

If creating a pointer is not your intention(I am not sure since you are migrating from java which doesn't have pointers), just use:

```
   HeatingUnit heatingUnit;
```

but do not use `new to allocate the memory in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ object are created without `new` unless you want to put them on the heap. To put them on the heap you'd need to use a pointer, e.g.

```
HeatingUnit* heatingUnit;
```

However, what you actually want is to initialize the object from the member initializer list:

```
BangBangControl(int tempToMaintain_, bool isOn, int initialTemp):
    heatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp),
    tempToMaintain(tempToMaintain_)
{
}
```

Comment: sweeet! what does the underscore in C++ do ("tempToMaintain_")

Comment: Well, I just attached the underscore to be sure that the names don't conflict. It isn't really necessary but I have to admit that I was unsure but just confirmed with a language expert sitting next to me (Richard Corden) that the first name refers to the member and the second to the name from the argument list if they are the same (i.e. you can safely remove the underscore).

Answer (score 0):

The variable declaration should be,

```
HeatingUnit *heatingUnit;
```

`new HeatingUnit` returns a pointer `HeatingUnit*` and to hold that you need a pointer.

For your information, here is another way (which has its limitation, but you feel somewhat like Java):

```
  private:
    HeatingUnit &heatingUnit;  // <--- declare reference
    int tempToMaintain;

  public:
    BangBangControl(int tempToMaintain, bool isOn, int initialTemp) :
    heatingUnit(*new HeatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp))
    {
      this -> tempToMaintain = tempToMaintain;
    }
```

Note that, we are defining `heatingUnit` in the initializer list of the constructor. You can do this for the `tempMaintain` as well.

Now `heatingUnit` can be used with `.` operator like Java instead of `->`.

All these apart, in C++ you should use `new` only if you want to do it dynamically. In your specific case, `HeatingUnit heatingUnit;` would suffice, which declares an automatic object and doesn't require any deallocation manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do:

```
heatingUnit= new HeatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp);
```

You have to change

```
HeatingUnit heatingUnit
```

to

```
HeatingUnit *heatingUnit
```

Why? Because in Java all objects can only hold *references* to objects by default, and to do that in C++ you have to declare it as a pointer, while in C++ objects can have sub-objects as fields (which can`t be done in Java).

Also, while in Java, initialization is done in the body of the constructor, it is good practice in C++ to use initialization lists.

```
BangBangControl(int tempToMaintain, bool isOn, int initialTemp)
: heatingUnit(new HeatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp)),
  tempToMaintain(tempToMaintain)
{ }
```

However, using `new` requires that you have to cleanup the memory yourself using `delete` so the following would be probably be preferable:

```
BangBangControl(int tempToMaintain, bool isOn, int initialTemp)
: heatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp),
  tempToMaintain(tempToMaintain)
{ }
```

Comment: when i use your technique i get "BangBangControl.cpp:18: error: member initializer expression list treated as compound expression
BangBangControl.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘HeatingUnit*’". Why is this happening?

Comment: @user937897: When using the first version (using `new`), declare `HeatingUnit *heatingUnit` with an asterisk, when using the second version (without `new`), declare `Heating heatingUnit` without the asterisk

Comment: sweet. your explanation was thorough and very helpful